# Elasticsearch client maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I have a webapp that takes advantage of Elasticsearch. I use an Elasticsearch standalone server and from the webapp side the transport client to communicate.

Currently I include the `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:1.3.4` dependency in my `pom.xml` and everything works fine. The point is that this dependency along with the transitives sum up to 20MB which is ridiculous. I just want to use the transport client.

Is there a more lightweight client dependency? Will ever be one? (I do not want to use jest or `httpclient` with the REST API).

Comment: have you tried to exclude some of the transitive dependencies? Maybe all the lucene stuff is not required? newer maven versions support wildcards in the exclusions.

Comment: Good idea, although I want something more straightforward and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for Elasticsearch Thrift. The thrift transport plugin allows to use the REST interface over thrift on top of HTTP.

It is a lightweight client which jar is around ~100kb and you also want the apache thrift jar library which is around ~3.4mb:

You can add these to your Maven dependencies :

For Elasticsearch-Thrift

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-transport-thrift</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and for the Apache-Thrift dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I trust you'll be able to find what version you'll need to use depending on your elasticsearch cluster version.

For more information about the elasticsearch-thrift check the [github project page](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-transport-thrift).

And check the apache thrift [official page](http://thrift.apache.org/) for Thrift.

**Edit:** Please keep in mind that according to github project page Thrift transport is deprecated as of Elasticsearch v1.5.0, and will be removed in 2.0.

Comment: Please keep in mind that according to github project page Thrift transport is deprecated as of Elasticsearch v1.5.0, and will be removed in 2.0.

Comment: I've answered that question 7 months ago. The roadmap was not clear. The solution I gave back then was viable and correct. I'll add your comment to the answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of development happened since this question was asked(2014), [Elasticsearch deprecated the transport client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) in favour of their [official Java high level rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html), which is a now a days a preferred and de-facto, Also new development in JEST is also stopped and it doesn't support the new versions of ES anymore.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Still, I found that the REST client without the Query DSL is of little use to me. And query DSL still needs the whole Elasticsearch dependency to work (actually it is part of the main dependency).